# ParamValue/Limitvalue is not appropriate error while using trim function in datastage

Tags: datastage

I am using Trim function in user variable activity in DS 7.5

```
Trim(Trim(ExCmd_EmailReptType.$CommandOutput,"*","L"),"#","T")
```

But job is aborting and showing an error as "Error calling DSSetParam(prmCNIRTP), code=-4 [ParamValue/Limitvalue is not appropriate]"

Can anybody help me with this ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer , when we face such issues we need to use @FM : Field Mark

```
Trim(Trim(EReplace(ExCmd_EmailReptType.$CommandOutput,@FM,""),"*", "L"),"#","T")
```

It's working now :-)